# Сравнить два значения и сделать жирным то, что больше

Tags: angular, table, primeng

есть таблица со столбцами, два из которых - даты.
Хочу сделать ближайшую дату жирной, т.е. сравнить обе даты в строке и ближайшую выделить.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать ?
Использую PrimeNG

```
<td>{{engine.KmChangeDate}}</td>                          
<td>{{engine.HourhangeDate}}</td>
```